# YouTube API - iframe onStateChange events

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the iframe YouTube API and I want to track events, for example, sending data to google analytics, when user start and stop video.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DjB1OvEYMhY"></iframe>
```

I looked https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1 and did not find an example how to do that. The example creates iframe and defines onReady and onStateChange as well. How would I do same when I've only iframe on page?

Comment: You should be able to put in an event handler along the lines of `function getPlayerState() {if (ytplayer) {return ytplayer. getPlayerState();}}`  - hopefully someone can demo how this produces results. Can't really help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This example listens to every play/pause action the user makes, using `onPlayerStateChange` with its different [**states**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events), and prints (*records*) them.

However, you need to create your own `record` function to do whatever you want with this data.

You also need an ID on your iframe (*#player* in this case) and to add *?enablejsapi=1* at the end of its URL. And of course, make sure to include the [Youtube iframe API](https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api).

**Note**

It's important to declare the API after your code, because it calls `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` when it's ready.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DjB1OvEYMhY?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
    <h5>Record of user actions:</h5>
    <script>
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player( 'player', {
          events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
        });
      }
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        switch(event.data) {
          case 0:
            record('video ended');
            break;
          case 1:
            record('video playing from '+player.getCurrentTime());
            break;
          case 2:
            record('video paused at '+player.getCurrentTime());
        }
      }
      function record(str){
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 8):

Here is a version that doesn't use Youtubes iframe API script. The only drawback is that the iframe API might change.

```
<iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

```
var addYoutubeEventListener = (function() {

    var callbacks = [];
    var iframeId = 0;

    return function (iframe, callback) {

        // init message listener that will receive messages from youtube iframes
        if(iframeId === 0) {
            window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {

                if(e.origin !== "https://www.youtube.com" || e.data === undefined) return;
                try {
                    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                    if(data.event !== 'onStateChange') return;

                    var callback = callbacks[data.id];
                    callback(data);
                }
                catch(e) {}
            });
        }

        // store callback
        iframeId++;
        callbacks[iframeId] = callback;
        var currentFrameId = iframeId;

        // sendMessage to frame to start receiving messages
        iframe.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var message = JSON.stringify({
                event: 'listening',
                id: currentFrameId,
                channel: 'widget'
            });
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, 'https://www.youtube.com');

            message = JSON.stringify({
                event: "command",
                func: "addEventListener",
                args: ["onStateChange"],
                id: currentFrameId,
                channel: "widget"
            });
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, 'https://www.youtube.com');
        });
    }
})();
```

```
addYoutubeEventListener(document.getElementById("player"), function(e) {

    switch(e.info) {
        case 1:
            // playing
            break;
        case 0:
            // ended
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the event load is not enough to ensure that the document inside the iframe is ready. If the iframe is in a different domain it is not possible to subscribe to see when it is ready.

A possible workaround is to record when an event is received from the iframe, if after subscribing no event was received try again:

```
var addYoutubeEventListener = (function() {

   var callbacks = [];
   var iframeId = 0;
   var subscribed = [];

   return function (iframe, callback) {
       // init message listener that will receive messages from youtube iframes
       if(iframeId === 0) {
           window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
               if(e.origin !== "https://www.youtube.com" || e.data === undefined) return;
               try {
                   var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                   subscribed[data.id] = true;
                   if(data.event !== 'onStateChange') return;

                   var callback = callbacks[data.id];
                   callback(data);
               }
               catch(e) {}
           }, true);
       }

       // store callback
       iframeId++;
       callbacks[iframeId] = callback;
       subscribed[iframeId] = false;
       var currentFrameId = iframeId;

       //console.log("adding event listener to iframe id " + iframeId);

       // sendMessage to frame to start receiving messages
       iframe.addEventListener("load", function () {
           var tries = 0;
           var checkSubscribed = function()
           {
               if (subscribed[currentFrameId]) {
                   //console.log("subscribed succesfully " + currentFrameId)
               }
               else
               {
                   tries++;
                   //console.log("Try again " + currentFrameId + " (" + tries + ")");
                   if (tries < 100) {
                       doSubscribe();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       console.log("Unable to subscribe" + currentFrameId );
                   }
               }
           }
           var doSubscribe = function()
           {
               var message = JSON.stringify({
                    event: 'listening',
                    id: currentFrameId,
                    channel: 'widget'
                });
                iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, 'https://www.youtube.com');

                message = JSON.stringify({
                    event: "command",
                    func: "addEventListener",
                    args: ["onStateChange"],
                    id: currentFrameId,
                    channel: "widget"
                });
                iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, 'https://www.youtube.com');
                setTimeout(checkSubscribed, 100);
            };
            doSubscribe();
       }, true);
   }
})();
```